# How can I include only part of a table caption in the content of tables when content of tables is so awkward?

Tags: table-of-contents

For my dissertation I am writing long captions on all my tables. This makes my content of tables very awkward, as each entry covers multiple lines. How can I specify a part of the caption to be included in the content of tables?

Answer (score 2):

This is provided, by default, by `\caption`'s optional argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\begin{figure}
  \caption[lipsum-1]{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \caption[lipsum-2]{\lipsum[2]}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is synonymous with the optional argument of sectional units which end up in the ToC.

Comment: Tank you.. but is there anyway that I can determine it by myself?

Comment: That *it* can determine it by itself?